# UE4 Blueprint: how to dynamically create mesh from array of vertex-coordinates of the polygon perimeter in the space

Tags: polygon, mesh, unreal-engine4, vertex, unreal-blueprint

How to create a mesh containing single polygon in a blueprint, if I only have the vertex-coordinates array (that describes outer perimeter points in space) of this polygon?

If I also had triangles data and UV data, I could use "Create Mesh Section" to create it, but perimeter coordinates are all I have.

Thank you!

Edit:
This is a spatial data of the borders of countries on the globe. So imagine a sphere with the size of 1 unit from which I am trying to cut out the silhouette of one country, having a lot of XYZ vertex-coordinates of its perimeter.

Comment: You will need to use some algorithm which triangulates the polygon.

Comment: It's not possible to create a dynamic mesh only with a perimeter, because you need to define the polygons and, then, their order will impact directly into your UV. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish but is this case common in your game/system?

Comment: @Fritz this is the default format for handling spatial data and I did build the silhouettes of countries in another engine with it before (using GLScene for Delphi). Unfortunately, I can't find a ready to go function that can calculate polygons based on the perimeter data in UE4.